# Find an element and add character to the string

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an object (obj) containing an array (create), I would like to access the create.field and modify 'test' to 'test_ID'. I have other data in the create array so I do not wish to erase it.

```
 const obj = {
 pro: 0,
 gr: 0,
 create: [
{
  field: "test",
  value: 12345
}
]
};
```

this is what I have now :

```
const test = obj.create.find((ele) => ele.field === 'OWNER'.join('_ID');
console.log('test', test);
```

Comment: your find needs to end `const owner = obj.create.find((ele) => ele.field === 'OWNER')` and then do the changes to the owner.field

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly you can do this

```
const newObject = {
    ...obj,
     create: obj.create.map(({ field, value }) => ({ field: field === "OWNER" ? `${field}_ID` : field, value })),
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to find element first, then you need to assign the `owner.field` property to its value plus the `_ID`

```js
 const obj = {
 pro: 0,
 gr: 0,
 create: [
{
  field: "OWNER",
  value: 12345
}
]
};

const owner = obj.create.find((ele) => ele.field === 'OWNER');
owner.field = owner.field +'_ID'
console.log('owner', owner);
console.log('obj', obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
const obj = {
   pro: 0,
   gr: 0,
   create: [
      {
        field: "OWNER",
        value: 12345
      }
   ]
};

let owner = obj.create.find(x => x.field == "OWNER");
if(owner) {
  owner.field = "OWNER_ID";
}
console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that using a `.map` function and an if check easily:

```js
const obj = {
  pro: 0,
  gr: 0,
  create: [
  {
    field: "OWNER",
    value: 12345
  }]
}
    
obj.create = obj.create.map(k => {
  return {
    ...k,
    field: k.field === "OWNER" ? "OWNER_ID" : k.field
  }
})

console.log(obj)
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit all:

```
obj.create=obj.create.map(e=>e.field+"_ID")
```

Edit all filtered:

```
obj.create=obj.create.map(e=>["OWNER"].includes(e.field)?(e.field+"_ID"):e.field)
```